# How to make spring not to add all model attributes to a redirect URL?

Tags: spring-mvc

When using old-styled (extends *Controller) controllers before we often used `return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/url"))` to return redirects from a Spring controller.

After upgrading to Spring 4.0 (@Controller) we've started to use `return "redirect:/url"` to do the same from @RequestMapping-annotated methods. However we've noticed that Spring adds *all* model attributes to a resulting redirect URL. This is *highly* undesirable behavior for us.

What makes matters worse: since those are added to a "Location" HTTP header (standard for HTTP 302) this makes Tomcat to throw an the following exception:

```
Aug 11, 2014 2:42:31 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor process
SEVERE: Error processing request
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.appendByte(AjpMessage.java:146)
```

One solution that comes to mind is clearing the model before every redirect, however this is rather cumbersome.

Is there a way to configure Spring not to add all model attributes to a redirect url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true"` to your `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag.

Comment: but I want this set to true only for one of the ModelAndView and controllers in the entire project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In a new application, or if your application does not depend on the usage of model attributed on redirect, you should add `ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true"` to the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag as Aramir said.

If it concerns only few new methods where other need the legacy mode, you can add a `RedirectAttribute` parameter to your method. As soon as it exists, Spring uses it instead of the model to determine which attributes should be used in redirected URL.