# Spring MVC Redirect shows parameters in applicationinfo.properties how to remove them

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, parameters

After using this way, the parameters in my properties files gets shown in the URL when redirected home page. 
(Ex: http://localhost:8080/home/?myproj.test.param.url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F . myproj.test.param.url is a property in my application info file )

```
public RedirectView save(@ModelAttribute("xxxxx") XXXX xp, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra) {

    return new RedirectView("/home/");

}
```

I tried  setting this false in my Web Config. It still did not work. 
  -requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);

I am using spring-webmvc-4.3. I used spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.15 to build.

Comment: I had some issues in a similar area recently. I think if you changed to  `return "redirect:/home/");` then the setting you have applied should fix it: Otherwise you need to set explicitly on the instance you have created: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html#setExposeModelAttributes-boolean-

Comment: Alternately, see here which suggests adding an empty RedirectAttribuites param to your controller method should fix: Or,  see here for an alternative: add a RedirectAttributes param to your method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256131/how-to-make-spring-not-to-add-all-model-attributes-to-a-redirect-url

Comment: Thanks Alan. I set the setExposeModelAttributes in Redirect View to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any one looking for an example code wise. The below code worked:

```
public RedirectView save(@ModelAttribute("xxxxx") XXXX xp, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/home/");
        redirectView.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
        return redirectView;
}
```